# JAVA GUI - two frames in one frame

Tags: java, swing, pdf, user-interface, frame

i tried to develop an application which is reading a directory and add for each map in this directory a button = Step 1. In step 2 the user klick on a button to show all the documents in that map. These (only PDF) documents are also show as buttons, if the user klick on the button the PDF will open in a viewer.

I defined two classes, and so on it works well. But now i have a problem with the layout. The buttons in step 1 are in one frame and the buttons ins step 2 are in an other frame. I want to have one frame so that on the left side are the dynamic buttons from step 1 and on the right side i want to have the buttons of step 2 or indeed of the buttons the PDf can also show as a tumblnail. If i click on a button on the left side the right side will be updated.

Can someone help me?

```
   package infopad;

   import java.awt.GridLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;

   import java.io.File;


   public class infopadUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   public infopadUI() {
    File directory = null;

    //Öffne Hauptverzeichnis
    directory = new File("c:/Produktordner");

    int numberfiles = 0;

    // Inhalt von directory
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();

         //Number of Products in directory
    numberfiles = files.length;

    setSize(600, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 6));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    for (int i = 1; i < numberfiles; i++) {
        //Name für Button aus Verzeichnisliste holen
        File file = files[i];

        JButton button = new JButton(file.getName());
        button.setActionCommand(file.getName());
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);

           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {


    new infopadUI().setVisible(true);



       }

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String  productnumber = e.getActionCommand();

    product p1 = new product(productnumber);       

       }



   }
```

---

```
   package infopad;

   import java.awt.Desktop;
   import java.awt.GridLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;

   import java.io.File;




   public class product extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public product(String productnumber)
{       
    String map;
    String doc;


    map = ("c:/Produktordner/")+productnumber;


    File directory = null;

    //Öffne Hauptverzeichnis
    directory = new File(map);

    int numberfiles = 0;

    // Inhalt von directory
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();

  //Number of Products in directory
    numberfiles = files.length;

    setSize(600, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 6));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    for (int i = 1; i < numberfiles; i++) {
        //Name für Button aus Verzeichnisliste holen
        File file = files[i];

        JButton button = new JButton(file.getName());
        doc = map+"/"+file.getName();



        button.setActionCommand(doc);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);

    }
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {




}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String  doc = ae.getActionCommand();

   try {
              Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(doc));
    } catch (Exception e) {}

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` instance from `InfoPadUI` to `Product` in the constructor: instead of `new infopadUI()....` do `new infopadUI(this)....` and in infopadUI change the constructor to accept a `JFrame`, and use that `JFrame` to put the button on. (get rid of JFrame in infopadUI)

Comment: But i have two different parts, one with the buttons of step 1 infopadui and one with the buttons of step2 product. if i don't klick on a button of step1, in part 2 no buttons will be shown. I was thinking about jsplitpane?

Comment: Yes, and then add another JPane inside the splitPane and pass  that to infopadUI, and let that add its buttons to that JPane